# I am willing to implement ros2_canopen with ros2_control

Tags: ros2, ros2-control

I am willing to implement ros2_canopen with ros2_control. I am new to ros2_canopen.

I have four wheels robot (in simulation) and using diff_drive as ros2_control. Everthing is working fine but when I am trying to use ros2_canopen with ros2_control, I am getting error: "Waiting for '/controller_manager' node to exist".

Can someone guide me? ros2_canopen documentation is not friendly to understand things properly.

May be I am doing something wrong with the bus.yml, ros2_control.yaml and ros2_control.xacro.

> bus.yml

```
options:
  dcf_path: "@BUS_CONFIG_PATH@"

master:
  node_id: 1
  driver: "ros2_canopen::MasterDriver"
  package: "canopen_master_driver"
  sync_period: 10000

defaults:
  dcf: "cia402_slave.eds"
  driver: "ros2_canopen::Cia402Driver"
  package: "canopen_402_driver"
  period: 10 # 1 ms
  heartbeat_producer: 1000 # Heartbeat every 1000 ms
  position_mode: 1 # Profile Position Mode
  sdo: # SDO executed during config
        - {index: 0x6081, sub_index: 0, value: 1000} # Set Profile Velocity
        - {index: 0x6083, sub_index: 0, value: 10000} # Set Profile Acceleration
        - {index: 0x6084, sub_index: 0, value: 10000} # Set Profile Deceleration
        - {index: 0x6085, sub_index: 0, value: 10000} # Set Quickstop Deceleration
        - {index: 0x6098, sub_index: 0, value: 0} # Set default Homing Method to 0 (No homing operation required)
        - {index: 0x60C2, sub_index: 1, value: 50} # Set Interpolation Time Period Value to 50 ms
        - {index: 0x60C2, sub_index: 2, value: -3} # Set Interpolation Time Index to 10-3s
  tpdo:
    1:
      enabled: true
      cob_id: "auto"
      transmission: 0x01
      mapping:
        - {index: 0x6041, sub_index: 0} # Statusword
        - {index: 0x6061, sub_index: 0} # Modes of Operation Display
    2:
      enabled: true
      cob_id: "auto"
      transmission: 0x01
      mapping:
        - {index: 0x6064, sub_index: 0} # Position Actual Value
        - {index: 0x606C, sub_index: 0} # Velocity Actual Value
    3:
      enabled: false
    4:
      enabled: false
  rpdo:
    1:
      enabled: true
      cob_id: "auto"
      mapping:
      - {index: 0x6040, sub_index: 0} # Controlword
      - {index: 0x6060, sub_index: 0} # Modes of Operation
    2:
      enabled: true
      cob_id: "auto"
      mapping:
      - {index: 0x607A, sub_index: 0} # Target Position
      - {index: 0x60FF, sub_index: 0} # Target Velocity
    3:
      enabled: false
    4:
      enabled: false

nodes:
  first_left_wheel_joint:
    node_id: 2
  first_right_wheel_joint:
    node_id: 3
  second_left_wheel_joint:
    node_id: 4
  second_right_wheel_joint:
    node_id: 5
```

> diffbot_controllers.yaml

```
controller_manager:
  ros__parameters:
    update_rate: 10  # Hz

    joint_state_broadcaster:
      type: joint_state_broadcaster/JointStateBroadcaster

    diffbot_base_controller:
      type: diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController

diffbot_base_controller:
  ros__parameters:
      
    joints:
      left_wheel_names: ["first_left_wheel_joint", "second_left_wheel_joint"]
      right_wheel_names: ["first_right_wheel_joint", "second_right_wheel_joint"]

    command_interfaces:
      - position
    state_interfaces:
      - position
      - velocity

    wheel_separation: 0.4
    #wheels_per_side: 1  # actually 2, but both are controlled by 1 signal
    wheel_radius: 0.1

    wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0
    left_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0
    right_wheel_radius_multiplier: 1.0

    publish_rate: 50.0
    odom_frame_id: odom
    base_frame_id: base_link
    pose_covariance_diagonal : [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01]
    twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.001, 0.01]

    open_loop: true
    enable_odom_tf: true

    cmd_vel_timeout: 0.5
    #publish_limited_velocity: true
    #velocity_rolling_window_size: 10

    # Velocity and acceleration limits
    # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
    linear.x.has_velocity_limits: true
    linear.x.has_acceleration_limits: true
    linear.x.has_jerk_limits: false
    linear.x.max_velocity: 1.0
    linear.x.min_velocity: -1.0
    linear.x.max_acceleration: 1.0
    linear.x.max_jerk: 0.0
    linear.x.min_jerk: 0.0

    angular.z.has_velocity_limits: true
    angular.z.has_acceleration_limits: true
    angular.z.has_jerk_limits: false
    angular.z.max_velocity: 1.0
    angular.z.min_velocity: -1.0
    angular.z.max_acceleration: 1.0
    angular.z.min_acceleration: -1.0
    angular.z.max_jerk: 0.0
    angular.z.min_jerk: 0.0
```

> diffbot.ros2_control.xacro

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:macro name="diffbot_ros2_control" params="name 
    use_mock_hardware
    prefix 
    bus_config
    master_config
    can_interface_name
    master_bin
  ">

    <ros2_control name="${name}" type="system">
      <xacro:unless value="${use_mock_hardware}">
        <hardware>
          <plugin>canopen_ros2_control/RobotSystem</plugin>
          <param name="bus_config">${bus_config}</param>
          <param name="master_config">${master_config}</param>
          <param name="can_interface_name">${can_interface_name}</param>
          <param name="master_bin">"${master_bin}"</param>
          <param name="example_param_hw_start_duration_sec">0</param>
          <param name="example_param_hw_stop_duration_sec">3.0</param>
        </hardware>
      </xacro:unless>
      <xacro:if value="${use_mock_hardware}">
        <hardware>
          <plugin>mock_components/GenericSystem</plugin>
          <param name="calculate_dynamics">true</param>
        </hardware>
      </xacro:if>
      <joint name="${prefix}first_left_wheel_joint">
        <param name="device_name">first_left_wheel_joint</param>
        <command_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="${prefix}first_right_wheel_joint">
        <param name="device_name">first_right_wheel_joint</param>
        <command_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="${prefix}second_left_wheel_joint">
        <param name="device_name">second_left_wheel_joint</param>
        <command_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
      <joint name="${prefix}second_right_wheel_joint">
        <param name="device_name">second_right_wheel_joint</param>
        <command_interface name="velocity"/>
        <state_interface name="position"/>
        <state_interface name="velocity"/>
      </joint>
    </ros2_control>

  </xacro:macro>

</robot>
```

> diffbot.urdf

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Basic differential drive mobile base -->
<robot xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro" name="diffdrive_robot">
  <xacro:arg name="prefix" default="" />
  <xacro:arg name="use_mock_hardware" default="false" />

  <xacro:include filename="diffbot_description.urdf.xacro" />

  <!-- Import Rviz colors -->
  <xacro:include filename="diffbot.materials.xacro" />

  <xacro:arg name="can_interface_name" default="vcan0" />
  <!-- Import diffbot ros2_control description -->
  <xacro:include filename="diffbot.ros2_control.xacro" />

  <xacro:diffbot prefix="$(arg prefix)" />

  <xacro:diffbot_ros2_control
    name="DiffBot" prefix="$(arg prefix)" use_mock_hardware="$(arg use_mock_hardware)"
    bus_config="$(find panda_canopen)/config/cia402/bus.yml"
    master_config="$(find panda_canopen)/config/cia402/master.dcf"
    can_interface_name="$(arg can_interface_name)"
    master_bin=""
  />

</robot>
```

> launch

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument, RegisterEventHandler, OpaqueFunction, IncludeLaunchDescription
from launch.conditions import IfCondition
from launch.event_handlers import OnProcessExit
from launch.substitutions import Command, FindExecutable, PathJoinSubstitution, LaunchConfiguration

from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare

from launch.launch_description_sources import PythonLaunchDescriptionSource

import yaml


def launch_setup(context, *args, **kwargs):

    can_interface_name = LaunchConfiguration("can_interface_name")

    nodes_to_start = []

    # Launch slaves nodes

    slave_launch = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("canopen_fake_slaves"), "launch", "cia402_slave.launch.py"]
    )

    bus_config = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("my_robot"), "config", "cia402", "bus.yml"]
    )

    with open(bus_config.perform(context), 'r') as f:
        bus_config_dict = yaml.safe_load(f)

    joints = []
    for key in bus_config_dict.keys():
        if "joint" in key:
            joints.append(key)

    for joint in joints:
        nodes_to_start.append(
            IncludeLaunchDescription(
                PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(slave_launch),
                launch_arguments={
                    "node_id": str(bus_config_dict[joint]["node_id"]),
                    "node_name": f"slave_node_{joint}",
                    "slave_config": PathJoinSubstitution([
                         FindPackageShare("my_robot"), "config", "cia402", str(bus_config_dict[joint]["dcf"])
                    ]),
                    "can_interface_name": can_interface_name,
                }.items(),
            )
        )

    # Launch master node

    master_launch = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("canopen_core"), "launch", "canopen.launch.py"]
    )

    master_config = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("my_robot"), "config", "cia402", "master.dcf"]
    )

    bus_config = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("my_robot"), "config", "cia402", "bus.yml"]
    )
    
    nodes_to_start.append(
        IncludeLaunchDescription(
            PythonLaunchDescriptionSource(master_launch),
            launch_arguments={
                "master_config": master_config,
                "master_bin": "",
                "bus_config": bus_config,
                "can_interface_name": can_interface_name,
            }.items(),
        )
    )

    return nodes_to_start


def generate_launch_description():
      
    # Declare arguments
    declared_arguments = []
    declared_arguments.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "gui",
            default_value="true",
            description="Start RViz2 automatically with this launch file.",
        )
    )
    declared_arguments.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "use_mock_hardware",
            default_value="false",
            description="Start robot with mock hardware mirroring command to its states.",
        )
    )

    # Initialize Arguments
    gui = LaunchConfiguration("gui")
    use_mock_hardware = LaunchConfiguration("use_mock_hardware")

    # Get URDF via xacro
    robot_description_content = Command(
        [
            PathJoinSubstitution([FindExecutable(name="xacro")]),
            " ",
            PathJoinSubstitution(
                [FindPackageShare("my_robot"), "urdf", "diff_robot.urdf"]
            ),
            " ",
            "use_mock_hardware:=",
            use_mock_hardware,
        ]
    )
    robot_description = {"robot_description": robot_description_content}

    robot_controllers = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [
            FindPackageShare("my_robot"),
            "config",
            "diffbot_controllers.yaml",
        ]
    )
    rviz_config_file = PathJoinSubstitution(
        [FindPackageShare("my_robot"), "diffbot/rviz", "diffbot.rviz"]
    )

    control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[robot_description, robot_controllers],
        output="both",
    )
    robot_state_pub_node = Node(
        package="robot_state_publisher",
        executable="robot_state_publisher",
        output="both",
        parameters=[robot_description],
        remappings=[
            ("/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel_unstamped", "/cmd_vel"),
        ],
    )
    rviz_node = Node(
        package="rviz2",
        executable="rviz2",
        name="rviz2",
        output="log",
        arguments=["-d", rviz_config_file],
        condition=IfCondition(gui),
    )

    joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["joint_state_broadcaster", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    robot_controller_spawner = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="spawner",
        arguments=["diffbot_base_controller", "--controller-manager", "/controller_manager"],
    )

    # Delay rviz start after `joint_state_broadcaster`
    delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[rviz_node],
        )
    )

    # Delay start of robot_controller after `joint_state_broadcaster`
    delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner = RegisterEventHandler(
        event_handler=OnProcessExit(
            target_action=joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
            on_exit=[robot_controller_spawner],
        )
    )

    nodes = [
        control_node,
        robot_state_pub_node,
        joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        delay_rviz_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
        delay_robot_controller_spawner_after_joint_state_broadcaster_spawner,
    ]

    declared_arguments.append(
        DeclareLaunchArgument(
            "can_interface_name",
            default_value="vcan0",
            description="CAN interface name to run the master and, when in simulation, the fake slaves.",
        )
    )

    return LaunchDescription(declared_arguments + nodes + [OpaqueFunction(function=launch_setup)])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can share the full error that will help more.
Second, you have

> bus.yml

```
position_mode: 1 # Profile Position Mode
```

it would help if you changed it to

```
velocity_mode: 1 # Profile velocity Mode
```

the same with the command interface should be velocity not position in

> diffbot_controllers.yaml

```
command_interfaces:
  - velocity
```

these changes may not fix your error but these are the correct settings for the diffbot.

Comment: Thank you! It helped!

As I am using simulation right now. Do you have idea how can I implement the same things on real hardware.?